# Write a Bayesian Network in BIFXML file

Tags: python, bayesian-networks

I am trying to generate random Bayesian Networks using pgmpy library and save them into BIFXML file using XMLBIFWriter.

My code so far is:

```
model = BayesianModel.get_random(10, 0.5, 2)
writer = XMLBIFWriter(model)
writer.get_definition()
writer.get_properties()
writer.get_states()
writer.get_values()
writer.get_variables()
writer.write_xmlbif('test.xml')
```

but I am getting this error: TypeError: cannot serialize 1 (type int)
Does this error occur because my variables(nodes) are ints? How can I solve this? Thank you!

Edit: I solved it. Turns out XMLBIFWriter is not compatible with the BN format you get from `get_random()` function so code in XMLBIFWriter needs to be changed. More specifically `boofar.text = foobar` needs to be replaced with `boofar.text = str(foobar)`